# Why doesn't this try/catch block catch the revert in `asset.symbol`?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, revert, try-catch

I wrote this Solidity function:

```
function getAssetSymbol(IERC20Metadata asset) internal view returns (string memory) {
    try asset.symbol() returns (string memory symbol) {
        return symbol;
    } catch {
        return "ERC20";
    }
}
```

And, while testing it, I realized that reverts are not caught when:

- `asset` is an address that doesn't contain code
- `asset` returns a `bytes32` instead of `string` (e.g. the MKR token does this)

Why is that? I was expecting try/ catch to handle these reverts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try..catch` doesn't catch the boundary exceptions, just the inner method call. Exactly that, what you have mentioned:

- checks if address is not void
- checks if `extcodesize` exists
- --checks if method exists-- This will be caught.

Any fails at this steps cause the revert. After the method is executed:

- checks if the return is as expected and can be decoded

A failure at this step also causes the revert.

Additional infos: [try-catch](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/control-structures.html?highlight=try%20catch#try-catch)

---

Sorry, initially I've written it reverts if the method does not exist. I was not sure about that and I was wrong, the call to an unexisting method **will be caught**. I think the method invocation is already at the inner contract level, as it executes a fallback method if any, otherwise reverts, which will be caught by the `try..catch`

Comment: Sorry Paul, the nonexisting method call will be caught by the `try..catch`